# "Can't find '__main__' module in" error whenever I try to run a python script in the command line

Tags: python

This is my batch file code:

```
@py C:\Users\Asus\Google Drive\Lifestyle\Technicals\Programming\Python\Python Scripts\Test.py %*
@pause
```

Alternatively, the same error appears when I try this line of code in the command line:

```
py.exe C:\Users\Asus\Google Drive\Lifestyle\Technicals\Programming\Python\Python Scripts\Test.py
```

My Test.py file has:

```
print('Hello')
```

Error Message:
[image]

Comment: Please add the full content of your Test.py file

Comment: `print('Hello')` that's the only code in my Test.py file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try doing

```
python "C:\Users\Asus\Google Drive\Lifestyle\Technicals\Programming\Python\Python Scripts\Test.py"
```

Command line does not like the " " (white space) character. Thus breaking your command.

You need to `cd directory` in the correct directory or either execute your command wrapped in double quotes

Comment: This works. Although I don't understand why the ones I posted in the main post did not work. When I had the batch file in my desktop it worked, but stopped working as soon as I moved it in the Google Drive folder.

Comment: I have updated my post ;) 
Please accept the answer if it is fine with you

Comment: Thanks I can only accept in 8 minutes will do later.

Comment: I have the same problem. I work on Mac and when I type: "python3 myScript.py" I get the same error: "can't find '__main__' module in myScript.py". Double quotes don't help. I don't know what is the problem.